# Batch File that Makes Driver Installations Quicker

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, installation, driver

I am trying to make a batch file that makes the process of installing multiple drivers a lot easier. It goes through each driver one by one, so all the user has to do is click "next" continuously through the whole process instead of having to keep track of which drivers are installed. Here is my code: The names of the drivers are in the text file and it uses a for loop to go through them.

The problem is that the first driver works fine, but the piece of code that tells the user what driver has just been installed and the total amount thats been installed, plus ask the user if they want to continue, does not work. After the first driver finishes, the rest just all open at the same time and don't go one by one as intended. It seems that the /wait code doesn't function anymore.

```
@echo off

:INTRO
ECHO Welcome to the Driver Installation Agent.
ECHO.
ECHO.

:GETINPUT
ECHO  Enter 1 - Start installing
ECHO.
ECHO  Enter 2 - Exit
ECHO.
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Enter the option: %=%
IF "%INPUT%" == "1" GOTO INSTALLAGENT
IF "%INPUT%" == "2" GOTO :EOF
GOTO INVALID

:INSTALLAGENT
set /a B=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (driverList.txt) do START %%A
GOTO FINISH


:START
start /s /wait %%A /NORESTART EULA_ACCEPT=YES
set /a B+=1
ECHO The driver %A% has just been installed, %B% drivers have been installed     in total.
ECHO  Enter 2 to exit, otherwise press enter to continue.
set INPUT2=
set /P INPUT2=Enter the option: %=%
IF "%INPUT2%" == "2" GOTO :EOF

:FINISH
ECHO
ECHO All Updates Performed. Press key to exit.
ECHO
PAUSE
cls

:INVALID
ECHO Invalid option
ECHO.
GOTO GETINPUT
```

I know this may not be the most efficient way to install drivers, but it has been bugging me and I think this is a good way to get introduced to coding in cmd. Any help would be helpful!

Comment: What if you change the order of the drivers on the list and say, put the one you currently have last? Does the same problem occur? It could be that the driver installer programs themselves aren't behaving the way you expect them to.

Comment: I changed the order, and the same thing still occurs. The first driver works fine, then the rest start at the same time once the second begins.

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet could help:

```
:INSTALLAGENT
set /a B=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (driverList.txt) do (
  set "_driver=%%~A"
  CALL :START
)
GOTO :FINISH

:START
start /s /wait %_driver% /NORESTART EULA_ACCEPT=YES
set /a B+=1
ECHO The driver %_driver% has just been installed, %B% drivers have been installed in total.
set "INPUT2="
set /P "INPUT2=Enter 2 to exit, otherwise press enter to continue: "
IF "%INPUT2%"=="2" goto :incomplete
GOTO :EOF

:INVALID
ECHO Invalid option
ECHO.
GOTO :GETINPUT

:FINISH
ECHO(
ECHO All Updates Performed. Press key to exit.
ECHO(
:incomplete
PAUSE
cls
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`CALL` command) [Call one batch program from another, or call a subroutine](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- (`%~A` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)